# Not able to remote desktop to home PC from office

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop

I am not able to access home PC (Windows10) from office PC (Windows 7) using remote desktop. To make sure, I don't have any wrong windows firewall settings, I have tried even when Windows Firewall is disabled. I have my port 3389 port open and listening.
Hope the below command is enough to verify my above statement.

```
netstat -a | findstr 3389
TCP    0.0.0.0:3389
```

Also, when I tried to remote desktop at home from my personal laptop (also running Windows 7) to home PC (Windows 10), then I am able to connect. Not sure, if this is due to the fact that both the nodes are connected to the same router.

I am including the information I have added to my router (port forward) settings.

```
Service Name    Remote 
Service Type    TCP/UDP
External Starting Port  3389        (1~65535)
External Ending Port    3389        (1~65535)
Use the same port range for Internal port - Yes
Internal Starting Port  3389      (1~65535)
Internal Ending Port    3389    
Internal IP address   192 .  168 .  0 .  29
External IP Address  Any
```

Comment: You need to look at port forwarding on your router (http://www.portforward.com for instructions).

Comment: Are you sure that "External IP Address" equal 0.0.0.0 allow any IP address? If it is a mask it might be a 255.255.255.255...

Comment: Is your external HOME IP address (on your router) a fixed IP address or a DHCP type address ? If it is DHCP (that is it changes from time to time) you will most likely also need a [Dynamic DNS Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) for your home LAN.

Comment: When you say your 'office PC' is that at work? Many companies lock down their firewalls in order to prevent employees from accessing the outside world, as a security measure. Do you have a work IT department you could ask about this?

Comment: @dotvotdot As far as I know, it is DHCP, since I have never configured my network to have a static IP address. So, I am assuming the default will be DHCP. Though, it changes from time to time, I do connect with the right external IP address, for that moment of time.

Comment: @g2mk That information is exactly taken from my Netgear router settings page.

Comment: @Adam That might be true. But, I should say that I am able to connect to my home PC using TeamViewer.

Comment: @Sandy: I assumed that, but what 0.0.0.0 mean in your router settings?

Comment: @g2mk Sorry about that, I should have clearly checked. It says 'Any'. And if I am right, 0.0.0.0 is supposed to be the format of the address.

Comment: @Sandy: Concern Adams comment. You can try to forward port 80 to port 3389 and try to connect from office by RDP on port 80. On what IP address are you trying to connect to your home machine? I hope that not on 192.168.0.29 but your router external IP address?

Comment: @g2mk When I tried to forward port 80 to 3389, this is the error that popped up. "The specified port(s) are being used by other configurations. Please check your configurations of USB Readyshare, Remote Management, Port Forwarding, Port Triggering and UPnP Port Mapping table." I am using this website: https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address to find my external ip address.

Comment: @Sandy: 80 is a HTTP port - I hope that you have WWW administration interface disabled from WAN side? You can try other popular ports:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_port#Common_port_numbers. Start from HTTPS, SSH, SMTP...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31701/discussion-between-sandy-and-g2mk).

Answer (score 0):

You can check port forwarding (your.external.ip.address:port -> your.internal.ip.address:port) by:

- Online external IP address finder / port scanner - http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ for example - from your home network.
- Telnet or just RDP to your.external.ip.address:port from place where network traffic isn't blocked.

If required port is opened on your router but don't work from your office you can try forward standard IP ports (HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, FTP, ...) to you internal IP address and RDP port (192.168.0.29:3389). You can try RDP to your.external.ip.address:forwarded_standard_port from your office then.